# If statement check in which table in database should store the data

Tags: php, mysql

I have a webpage that contains a dropdownlist and some textfiedls, what I want to do is to check the lecturer name from the dropdown list as we can see in the image below 
[image]

and store in the data from the rest of the form in the database table which the lecture name is the same with the  table name.
My php code is the below

```
<?php

define('DB_NAME','mydb');
define('DB_USER','root');
define('DB_PASSWORD','');
define('DB_HOST','localhost');

$connect = mysql_connect(DB_HOST,DB_USER,DB_PASSWORD);

if(!$connect){
    die('Could not connect:'.mysql_error());
}

$db_selected=mysql_select_db(DB_NAME,$connect);

if(!$db_selected){
    die('Can\'t use'.DB_NAME.':'.mysql_error());
}
$dim = $_POST['dim'];
$lag = $_POST['lag'];
$stam = $_POST['stam'];
$keh = $_POST['keh'];
$chry = $_POST['chry'];



if(HERE I WANT TO CHECK THAT IF THE LECTURER NAME IS EQUAL TO DIMOPOULOS THEN DO THE BELOW)
{

$value1=$_POST['a1'];
$value2=$_POST['a2'];
$value3=$_POST['a3'];
$value4=$_POST['l1'];
$value5=$_POST['l2'];
$value6=$_POST['r1'];
$value7=$_POST['r2'];
$value8=$_POST['u1'];
$value9=$_POST['u2'];
$value10=$_POST['u3'];
$value11=$_POST['unit_name'];
$value12=$_POST['year'];

$sql="INSERT INTO dimopoulos(a1,a2,a3,l1,l2,r1,r2,u1,u2,u3,unit_name,year) VALUES('$value1','$value2','$value3','$value4','$value5','$value6','$value7','$value8','$value9','$value10','$value11','$value12')";

if(!mysql_query($sql)){
    die('Error:'.mysql_error());

}  
}
elseif(HERE I WANT TO CHECK THAT IF THE LECTURER IS EQUAL TO LAGKAS THEN DO THE BELOW)
{
  $value1=$_POST['a1'];
$value2=$_POST['a2'];
$value3=$_POST['a3'];
$value4=$_POST['l1'];
$value5=$_POST['l2'];
$value6=$_POST['r1'];
$value7=$_POST['r2'];
$value8=$_POST['u1'];
$value9=$_POST['u2'];
$value10=$_POST['u3'];
$value11=$_POST['unit_name'];
$value12=$_POST['year'];

$sql="INSERT INTO lagkas(a1,a2,a3,l1,l2,r1,r2,u1,u2,u3,unit_name,year) VALUES('$value1','$value2','$value3','$value4','$value5','$value6','$value7','$value8','$value9','$value10','$value11','$value12')";

if(!mysql_query($sql)){
    die('Error:'.mysql_error());

}   
}
elseif(HERE I WANT TO CHECK THAT IF THE LECTURER IS EQUAL TO STAMATOPOULOU THEN DO THE BELOW)
{
  $value1=$_POST['a1'];
$value2=$_POST['a2'];
$value3=$_POST['a3'];
$value4=$_POST['l1'];
$value5=$_POST['l2'];
$value6=$_POST['r1'];
$value7=$_POST['r2'];
$value8=$_POST['u1'];
$value9=$_POST['u2'];
$value10=$_POST['u3'];
$value11=$_POST['unit_name'];
$value12=$_POST['year'];

$sql="INSERT INTO stamatopoulou(a1,a2,a3,l1,l2,r1,r2,u1,u2,u3,unit_name,year) VALUES('$value1','$value2','$value3','$value4','$value5','$value6','$value7','$value8','$value9','$value10','$value11','$value12')";

if(!mysql_query($sql)){
    die('Error:'.mysql_error());

}   
}
elseif(HERE I WANT TO CHECK THAT IF THE LECTURER IS EQUAL TO KEHAGIAS THEN DO THE BELOW)
{
  $value1=$_POST['a1'];
$value2=$_POST['a2'];
$value3=$_POST['a3'];
$value4=$_POST['l1'];
$value5=$_POST['l2'];
$value6=$_POST['r1'];
$value7=$_POST['r2'];
$value8=$_POST['u1'];
$value9=$_POST['u2'];
$value10=$_POST['u3'];
$value11=$_POST['unit_name'];
$value12=$_POST['year'];

$sql="INSERT INTO kehagias(a1,a2,a3,l1,l2,r1,r2,u1,u2,u3,unit_name,year) VALUES('$value1','$value2','$value3','$value4','$value5','$value6','$value7','$value8','$value9','$value10','$value11','$value12')";

if(!mysql_query($sql)){
    die('Error:'.mysql_error());

}   
}
elseif(HERE I WANT TO CHECK THAT IF THE LECTURER IS EQUAL TO CHRYSOCHOOU THEN DO THE BELOW)
{
  $value1=$_POST['a1'];
$value2=$_POST['a2'];
$value3=$_POST['a3'];
$value4=$_POST['l1'];
$value5=$_POST['l2'];
$value6=$_POST['r1'];
$value7=$_POST['r2'];
$value8=$_POST['u1'];
$value9=$_POST['u2'];
$value10=$_POST['u3'];
$value11=$_POST['unit_name'];
$value12=$_POST['year'];

$sql="INSERT INTO chrysochoou(a1,a2,a3,l1,l2,r1,r2,u1,u2,u3,unit_name,year) VALUES('$value1','$value2','$value3','$value4','$value5','$value6','$value7','$value8','$value9','$value10','$value11','$value12')";

if(!mysql_query($sql)){
    die('Error:'.mysql_error());

}   
}
mysql_close();

?>
```

and my html code is this...

```
<html>
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../../statistics/style.css">
<script type="text/javascript">
    function resetForm(){
    // clearing selects
      var selects = document.getElementsByTagName('select');
       for (var i = 0; i<selects.length; i++)
     selects[i].selectedIndex = 0;

    return false;
    }
    window.load(resetForm());
</script>
</head>
<body>
<div id="nav">
    <div id="nav_wrapper">
    <ul>
        <li><a href="#">Principal</a>
        <ul>
            <li><a href="../../statistics/principalLecturerForm.php">Lecturer Scores</a></li>
            <li><a href="../../statistics/principalServicesForm.php">Services Scores</a></li>
            <li><a href="../../statistics/principalLecturerYears.php">Lecturer Over the Years</a></li>

        </ul>

        </li>
        <li><a href="#">Academic Director</a>
        <ul>
            <li><a href="../../statistics/ac_directorLecturerForm.php">Lecturer Scores</a></li>
            <li><a href="../../statistics/ac_directorServicesForm.php">Services Scores</a></li>
            <li><a href="../../statistics/ac_directorLecturerYears.php">Lecturer Over the Years</a></li>

        </ul>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#">Lecturer</a>
        <ul>
            <li><a href="../../statistics/lecturerForm.php">Lecturer</a></li>
            <li><a href="../../statistics/lecLecturerYears.php">Lecturer Over the Years</a></li>
        </ul>
        </li>

        <li><a href="#">Admin</a>
        <ul>
            <li><a href="../../statistics/adminFormLecturer.php">Save Lecturer Scores</a></li>
            <li><a href="../../statistics/adminFormServices.php">Save Services Scores</a></li>
            <li><a href="../../statistics/upload.php">Update Lecturers</a></li>
        </ul>
        </li>
        <li><a href="../../statistics/logout.php">Logout</a></li>
    </ul>
    </div>
</div>
<br />
<br />
<br /> 

    <div id="lecform">

    <form action="savelagkasscores.php" method="POST">

    <b>Lecturers:<b/>
    <select name="lecturer"> 
    <option value="Choose">Please select..</option>
    <option id="dim" value="dimopoulos">Dimopoulos</option> 
    <option id="lag" value="lagkas">Lagkas</option>
    <option id="stam" value="stamatopoulou">Stamatopoulou</option>
    <option id="keh" value="kehagias">Kehagias</option>
    <option id="chry" value="chrysochoou">Chrysochoou</option></select><br/><br/>
    <br />
    A1: <input type="text" name="a1" size="5"> <br /><br/>
    A2: <input type="text" name="a2" size="5"> <br /><br/>
    A3: <input type="text" name="a3" size="5"> <br /><br/>
    L1: <input type="text" name="l1" size="5"> <br /><br/>
    L2: <input type="text" name="l2" size="5"> <br /><br/>
    R1: <input type="text" name="r1" size="5"> <br /><br/>
    R2: <input type="text" name="r2" size="5"> <br /><br/>
    U1: <input type="text" name="u1" size="5"> <br /><br/>
    U2: <input type="text" name="u2" size="5"> <br /><br/>
    U3: <input type="text" name="u3" size="5"> <br /><br/>
    Unit Name:<input type="text" name="unit_name" size="20"> <br /><br/>
    Year:<input type="text" name="year" size="10"> <br /><br/>

    <br/>
    <input type="submit" value="submit" name="Save">
    <input type="reset" name="reset" value="Clear">

    </form>
    </div>
    <br />
    <br />
     <div id="footer">

        Copyright e-Statistics 2015

    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

What i cant do is to find the appropriate if statements for each of the ifs that i have in the php code in order to save the data in the correct table in the database.

Comment: As a side remark, I have the feeling your database is very poorly designed. I don't see any good reason for having 1 table for each lecturer. Your records would probably be better stored in the same table with a lecturer field or so... While it might work now, with your current needs, it would : 1) Work better now 2) Be way more future-proof 3) Be more performant  ... if you were using a nomalized database...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No need to go for IF ELSE you can simply write the dynamic insert statement where  will be a dynamic variable, and Yes you must have to pass related TABLE_NAME as a variable from UI during form submission.

```
$MY_TABLE=$_POST['TABLE_NAME'];

$sql="INSERT INTO {$MY_TABLE} (a1,a2,a3,l1,l2,r1,r2,u1,u2,u3,unit_name,year) VALUES('$value1','$value2','$value3','$value4','$value5','$value6','$value7','$value8','$value9','$value10','$value11','$value12')";
```

Comment: Yes and $lecturer you can pass into your query as inplace of table name, If such table exist in your DB it will insert the data and you are done.

Answer (score -1):

You can simply check with the directly by names.

```
if ($dim == 'dimopoulos') { 
... 
} elseif ($lag == 'lagkas') {
... 
} // same way try for all
```

Comment: Too many if statements and if they want to add new lecturers then they will need to add new if statements and that's not good for any software to have many `if`